# What is the marked-up text/document resulted from proofreading called?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a manuscript is proofread, reviewed, revised or corrected, are there any single-word noun to refer to it? (I'm looking for a real noun not edited, unedited etc.)

*update*
example: "On this table you place the drafts and on that table you can pick up the ...".

Please also mention if you know other words for drafts. I mean a document or some text that may contain errors of any kind (grammar, style, ...)

Comment: "Text", I guess.  It's certainly not "perfect text" or even "error-free text".

Comment: Do you want a word for the marked-up copy, or for the clean text produced in response to the edits? You should add a sentence showing how you want to use the word for the best responses.

Comment: When I arrived at my first job, there still existed a typing pool lead by some formidable old bats, some of whom had been warming their chairs since the start of WWII. These were dubbed the *battleaxes* by us young engineers, and we called the  copy they returned; unimpeachable, uniform, and bearing no particular resemblance to that submitted;  *battle axage*.

Comment: @1006a maked-up copy. an example is added.

Comment: @PHPst Does it have to be one word? Maybe you could use something like *revised edition* or *revised texts*.

Comment: Can you just call it “the mark-ups”?

Comment: @Jazzachi Yes, I need one word as it will be frequently used in my software.

Comment: Just guessing here, but could the term galley (or galleys) be appropriate? Also known as advanced reader copies, these printed versions of books which are distributed gratis to reviewers and other industry insiders are not in their final form, and as such they may contain some infelicities of grammar, spelling,  and text layout, and may have a temporary, perhaps even primitive, cover design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would normally go with "revision" or "revised text."

> **revision** *noun*
>   1.1 (count noun) A revised edition or form of something.
>   ‘Twenty-three revisions were then made and two complete re-writes carried out.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revision)

Comment: Please include support for your answers. I've added a dictionary entry and a relevant example. (I didn't down-vote, by the way.)

Comment: @Lawrence The post was automatically flagged for low quality (because of its brevity). You validated that flag by editing the post -- that is, the post *was* of low quality. Validating an automatic low-quality flag imposes an automatic -1, which can be reversed if the edit makes the answer sufficiently good to merit an upvote. [Meta SE explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/276474/184638)

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's counterintuitive that trying to help ended up causing a down-vote; this allows users to effectively down-vote twice if they were so inclined). Thanks for the explanation though - much appreciated. I was going to post *revision* as an answer before seeing BLKenny's, so I'll go ahead and up-vote it back to 0.

Answer (score 2):

In the educational publishing world, the stages of edited ms are often called "passes" or "pages." (Passes in Canada, pages in Australia.)

After the initial edit, the document goes to a designer. Once the designer has completed his or her work, *first pages* (or the *first pass*) are returned to the editor (as well as various other people, usually the publisher and if the first pages are in good enough shape, the author) for further correction.

Ensuing rounds of corrections are referred to as *second pages/pass*, *third pages/pass*, and, if required, *fourth pages/pass*. (It's really been a struggle in production if a fourth pass is required!)

(Source: I have 18 years of experience in educational publishing.)

Answer (score 1):

[Proof reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofreading) and [copy editing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_editing) are part of the editorial cycle for a manuscript, and hopefully results in publication.

The cycle generally consists of:

- Raw manuscript
- Edit
- Proof-read/copy edit
- ????
- Publication

Between the stages of proof read and publication, there is an **[advance copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_copy)** (noun phrase - sorry!), which 'tests the water' before a fully-fledged publication drive.